# LineInput Function In Pascal

Tags: vb.net, pascal

In VB there is a function called LineInput (More info - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e33ddk1(v=vs.90).aspx)

Is there one for Pascal? Or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ReadLn`](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html).